# Move files from a docker container to an outside folder on the same server using php

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I am fairly new to docker, please bear with me if its a basic question. I have a laravel project on a server, the project is dockerized. What I want to do is move a file from my project to another location on the same server that is not dockerized.

So, my project is setup on `/var/www/my-project` directory and I want to copy a file from `my-project/storage/app/public/file.csv` to `/var/{destination_folder}`. How can I do that in laravel? I think my issue is not related to laravel it is related to docker which is not allowing to move files out of it. Please don't add laravel or php file copy code snippets,I have tried plenty.

What I've tried?

1- I have tried copying file using:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('/var/{destination_folder}', 'my-project/storage/app/public/file.csv' )
```

but, it does not copy the file.

2- I have also tried moving the file using bash script which I'm executing from my laravel controller using `shell_exec` or `process` but, it is also not working.

```
cp "/var/www/my-project/storage/app/public/file.csv" "/var/destination_folder"
```

What's hapening in this solution is that it is working when I run the command from terminal, but its not working when I call it from my controller and it gives me

`cp: cannot create regular file '/var/destination_folder/file.csv': No such file or directory`

After googling the above error it seemed that this is a permission issue wo, I changed the permission of the destination folder to 775 and I also checked the user from which I was running the laravel app and it gave me root when I ran `whoami` from the app.

Let me know how this could be achieved, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire point of docker is that it is isolated from the base host. You cannot simply copy the file out, as the docker host does not have access to any disk that is not mounted.

The easiest option is to create a destination directory and create a bind mount as per https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

You would then use the following argument for your docker run:
--mount type=bind,source=/var/destination_folder,target=/some_directory_inside_your_docker and copy the file to some_directory_inside_your_docker and it will appear in the parent host.

Another option is to generate a user account on the parent host, LOCK IT DOWN HARD for security reasons, and then have a private key inside your docker that would allow your docker to SSH to the parent host (note, this won't work with every network configuration). I don't think it's a good idea when you can do bind mounts, but it *would* work.

Comment: Hi @Xaraxia, I tried your mount suggestion but it didn;t worked. The mount was successful though when I verified it using docker inspect. But, when I copy the file in the {some_directory_inside_your_docker} it didn't appeared in {/var/destination}

Comment: Did you work this out? If not, if you drop a file into /var/destination does it turn up in some_directory_inside_your_docker?

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry for the late reply. I actually used volumes in docker-composer.yml like: 
volumes: 
    - /var/destination_folder/:/some_directory_inside_your_docker
Please make sure to restart docker container.